# Missing space before "and" in author list with two \thanks

Tags: spacing, footnotes, titles

I am trying to typeset the authors' names in a paper so that they appear as

### Joe Bloggs* and John Smith**

(i.e. typeset with a joining "and" and normal spacing between words). I also need to put a `\thanks` for each author. The code I am using is

```
\author{
  Joe Bloggs\thanks{blah}\ and\ John Smith\thanks{blah}
}
```

But this has the downside that there is no space between the footnote symbol on "Bloggs" and "and" so what i get looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get LaTeX to put a space in there?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{The Title}
\author{Joe Bloggs\thanks{blah}\ and\ John Smith\thanks{blah}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just leave a space after thanks: `\thanks{blah} \ and` should be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is to redefine `\and` and use it. Anyways, the footnotemark is printed `\rlap`ped in the `\author`, i.e. occupying no space. If we disable `\rlap`, everything works fine.

The "proper" code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\and{\end{tabular}\kern-\tabcolsep\ and\ \kern-\tabcolsep\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\let\origthanks\thanks
\renewcommand\thanks[1]{\begingroup\let\rlap\relax\origthanks{#1}\endgroup}

\title{The Title}
\author{Joe Bloggs\thanks{blah} \and John Smith\thanks{blah}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The code that only disables `\rlap` and does not modify anything else:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\origthanks\thanks
\renewcommand\thanks[1]{\begingroup\let\rlap\relax\origthanks{#1}\endgroup}

\title{The Title}
\author{Joe Bloggs\thanks{blah}\ and\ John Smith\thanks{blah}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The output of both codes is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works. I notice that the solution in the comment by @Corentin above: "leave a space after thanks: `\thanks{blah} \ and` should be ok" also produces the desired effect. Whilst this may not be the proper way to do things, is there any adverse consequence of this simpler solution?

Comment: @Ubiquitous Yes, there is, but sort-of theoretical: If the symbol were something thicker (like `**`) or something thinner (like I don't know what, `!`), the space would have the wrong length, because you compensate the variable width of the symbol by a fixed interword space.